# How to add alias to a TypeScript interface for an existing property?

Tags: typescript, interface

How can I achieve to assign the type of another property?

```
// 3rd party interface
interface A {
   foo: FooType
}

// my desired solution
interface B extends A {
   bar: typeof A.foo
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use square bracket notation: `A['foo']`

```js
// 3rd party interface
interface A {
   foo: FooType
}

// my desired solution
interface B extends A {
   bar: A['foo'] // here is the solution
}
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty easy. I tried all kind of funky syntax, generics and such. However, unfortunately it cannot maintain the DocBlock documentation in WebStorm :( Any idea for that?

Comment: What do you mean: DocBlock documentation in WebStorm ?
 I'm not familiar with WS at all

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-architecture-6ppe6 Same in VSCode also. Try __CTRL+Hover__ `foo` and `bar` also in `x`. You'll see the DocBlock for `foo` but not for `bar`.

Comment: @wintercounter You haven't added docs for `bar`, if you do it works like you expect: https://imgur.com/a/ot6Wn1H If you want to know more, that's a separate question entirely.

Comment: Yep, I will, just showing what I meant. Since I use the type of `foo` I also want to the DocBlock from `foo` for `bar`. That's my point. Thanks anyway, opening a new question.

Comment: This also works to create aliases within an interface definition, including for functions. For example I'm extending `EventTarget` to deliver custom `Event`s and want to add shorter aliases like `on`, `off`, `once` etc.  The definitions for custom event handlers are absurdly long and repetitive already (separate topic!), including 2 long lines each for `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` (see `lib.dom.d.ts`). So having aliases to my short versions is a big win in my book.  And so simple in the end....  thank you!

Comment: @MaximPaperno you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe)